# SQL Server, bat-ник BackUpDb не Work-ает

Tags: sql, sql-server, bat

Проблема в следующем.
На просторе интернета нашёл такой скрипт

```
@echo off
set dd=%DATE:~0,2%
set mm=%DATE:~3,2%
set yyyy=%DATE:~6,4%
set curdate=%dd%-%mm%-%yyyy%
set username=***
set password=***

set db=TestDB
sqlcmd -S server -U %username% -P %password% -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [%db%] TO DISK = N'PathFromDisk\%db%_%curdate%.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NAME = N'%db%-full', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION, STATS = 10"
```

Собственно вопрос, как написать путь (**PathFromDisk**), до папки куда нужно сохранить резервную копию базы данных?

Если сама база находиться на сервере (192.16...), а резервную копию нужно сделать на локальную машину.

Пробовал писать адрес по сети \\XXX\DB, пробовал писать 192.16....\\XXX\DB

Comment: Так команда выполняется на **удаленном** сервере. Значит **локальная машина**, куда надо положить резервную копию, **должна** предоставить ресурсы для SQL-сервера (например файловые). Чтобы удаленный SQL-сервер мог положить туда bak-файл. Либо используйте файловый сервер, либо расшарьте папку с резервной копией на SQL-сервере для Вашего локального сервера.

Comment: @Daemon-5 Спасибо за ответ! Не могли бы объяснить вот это (должна предоставить ресурсы для SQL-сервера (например файловые))

Comment: Для этого надо понимать, как **создавать и использовать сетевые ресурсы** Windows-сервера, используя встроенные средства: это либо #1 SMB, либо #2 FTP. #2 - это добавить FTP-сервис на одну из машин: локальную или на SQL-сервере.Затем ftp-клиентом забирать оттуда бэкап. #1 - расшарить локальную папку SQL-сервера (**PathFromDisk**) , а с локальной машины уже копировать её: **copy \\192.168...\share\*.bak c:\Folder1**. И в том? и в другом случае сценарии можно вызывать как с SQL-сервера, так и с локальной машины. P.S. Как авторизоваться при обращении к ресурсам - это уже чисто технический вопрос.

Comment: Я понимаю, что есть и другие способы. Начиная от создания SQL-зеркала, использования BITS, либо Windows backup, DFS, внешних robocopy, rsync и  и т.д. Но самые очевидные средства - это SMB файл-сервер (промежуточный, либо на одной из машин). Выбор зависит от наличия соответствующей инфраструктуры.

Comment: @Daemon-5 Спасибо! Вроде понятно!